# NHibernate QueryOver Conversion Error On DB2 Date Type

Tags: db2, queryover

I'm new to NHibernate and I am hoping I can find some assistance in tracking down the source of a conversion error I'm getting when trying to use a DateTime comparison for a predicate.

```
return _session.QueryOver<ShipmentSegment>()
                .Where(ss => ss.SegmentOrigin == selOrig)
                // Whenever I add the predicate for the SegmentDate below
                // I receive a conversion error
                .And(ss => ss.SegmentDate == selDate)
                .List<ShipmentSegment>();
```

**Exception**

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was unhandled by user code
  Message=could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.ajpro# as ajpro1_28_0_, this_.ajleg# as ajleg2_28_0_, this_.ajpu# as ajpu3_28_0_, this_.ajlorig as ajlorig28_0_, this_.ajldest as ajldest28_0_, this_.segdate as segdate28_0_, this_.ajldptwin as ajldptwin28_0_, this_.ajlfrtype as ajlfrtype28_0_, this_.ajlfrdest as ajlfrdest28_0_, this_.ajtpmfst# as ajtpmfst10_28_0_, this_.ajspplan as ajspplan28_0_, this_.ajhload as ajhload28_0_ FROM go52cst.tstshprte this_ WHERE this_.ajlorig = @p0 and this_.segdate = @p1 ]
  Name:cp0 - Value:WIC  Name:cp1 - Value:3/28/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

**Inner Exception**

```
Message=A conversion error occurred.
       Source=IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       MessageCode=111
       MessageDetails=Parameter: 2.
       SqlState=""
       StackTrace:


 - at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Exception.throwDcException(MpDcErrorInfo
 mpEI, MPConnection conn)
 - at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Command.openCursor()
 - at IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Command.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
 behavior)
 - at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
 - at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
 - at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection,
   ISessionImplementor session)
 - at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
 - at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor
   session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
 - at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
```

I appreciate anything that can help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with this specific iSeries exception came from when I was creating a parameter (of iDB2TypeParameter) for the ADO.NET command parameter list for a store procedure type ADO command. I had to explicitly tell what kind of iDB2DbType to use: iDB2DbType.Date, iDB2DbType.Time or iDB2DbType.TimeStamp. The iSeries ADO provider can't possibly know which of the three types to use when you create a parameter from a .NET System.DateTime type.

```
new iDB2Parameter(parameterName, iDB2DbType.Date){ Value = myValue };
new iDB2Parameter(parameterName, iDB2DbType.Time){ Value = myValue };
new iDB2Parameter(parameterName, iDB2DbType.TimeStamp){ Value = myValue };
```

I realize that you are not creating your parameters manually like this example but instead using NHibernate. So, I would make sure that NHibernate's LINQ provider for DB2/iSeries is aware of this. That's nothing against NHibernate, I just find it nearly impossible to find good, solid ORM for DB2/iSeries.