# Db2: c# Nhibernate using time column as TimeAsTimeSpan throws exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, db2

I have this simple query that is throwing an exception (see below).

The *myTable* table has a column that is of type **Time** and nHibernate tries
to convert that to **TimeSpan** via a Int64.

I saw that there is that TimeAsTimeSpan convention when using a mapping.

But I didn’t have any mapping.

So how could I achieve that without using a mapping ?

**myCode**

```
        string sqlText = "Select * from myTable";

        ISQLQuery query = Session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlText);

        query.List(); // <-- fails with exception
```

**Exception thrown**

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query
System.FormatException: Input string '10:01:40' was not in the correct format. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
   at System.Convert.ToInt64(Object value)
   at NHibernate.Type.TimeSpanType.Get(DbDataReader rs, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Type.TimeSpanType.Get(DbDataReader rs, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(DbDataReader rs, String name, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.Extract(Object[] data, DbDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ResultRowProcessor.ExtractResultRow(Object[] data, DbDataReader resultSet, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Custom.CustomLoader.ResultRowProcessor.BuildResultRow(Object[] data, DbDataReader resultSet, Boolean hasTransformer, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
```

**Setup:**
nhibernate 5.2,
.net 4.6.2,
database is Db2

Comment: hi, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910693/nhibernate-queryover-conversion-error-on-db2-date-type/11513117

Comment: Hi mshabou, thanks for the answer but this is not the problem, its about TimeSpan is not detected as db2.Time its detected as db2.Int64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution for this, so if anyone had the same problem.
Here is the solution.

You have to register the type to the typefactory as TimeAsTimeSpanType

like this:

```
TypeFactory.RegisterType(typeof(TimeSpan), new TimeAsTimeSpanType(), new List<string> { "TimeSpan" });
```